# filling up a file with a record with escaped chars

Tags: bash, strings

I have this record of a csv:

```
"0258327469@pippo.it","456281438","16274","782981244047720"," ","<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" width=""100%"" align=""center"" style=""font-size:0;""><tr>","","","","",""
```

I need to fill a file until I reach a specified size of the file. I would use a simple loop putting in append the same row. Is there a way with echo to just write this line including every `"` encountered?

If I use `echo -e` I got

```
eianni@ianni-desktop:~/Desktop$ echo -e "0258327469@pippo.it","456281438","16274","782981244047720"," ","<table cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" border=""0"" width=""100%"" align=""center"" style=""font-size:0;""><tr>","","","","",""
0258327469@pippo.it,456281438,16274,782981244047720, ,<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% align=center style=font-size:0;><tr>,,,,,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent bash from processing the quotes by wrapping the whole argument to `echo` in single-quotes.
`echo -e '"0258327... .."",""'` should do the trick.